# lightning:datatable table headers are disappearing in iPad safari browser

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, datatable, lightning-datatable, ipad

I am using lightning:datatable, the table headers are disappearing in iPad safari browser when I try to resize the coloum headers by draging.
Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: Did you find any solution or workaround?